llm chain for llama is throwing error that input should be an instance of runnable
I have the following code
quantization_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(load_in_4bit=True,
                                         llm_int4_enable_fp32_cpu_offload=True)

sumModel = "meta-llama/Llama-3.2-1B"

llm_llama_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    sumModel,
    torch_dtype=torch.float32,
    temperature =0,
    device_map='auto',
    quantization_config=quantization_config
)

llm_llama_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(sumModel)

summary_chain = load_summarize_chain(llm=llm_llama_model, chain_type='map_reduce',
                                      verbose=True # Set verbose=True if you want to see the prompts being used
                                    )

and i am getting the following error:
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-d8e6a6acabfd> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 summary_chain = load_summarize_chain(llm=llm_llama_model, chain_type='map_reduce',
      2                                       verbose=True # Set verbose=True if you want to see the prompts being used
      3                                     )

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pydantic/main.py in __init__(self, **data)
    210         # `__tracebackhide__` tells pytest and some other tools to omit this function from tracebacks
    211         __tracebackhide__ = True
--> 212         validated_self = self.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(data, self_instance=self)
    213         if self is not validated_self:
    214             warnings.warn(

ValidationError: 2 validation errors for LLMChain
llm.is-instance[Runnable]
  Input should be an instance of Runnable [type=is_instance_of, input_value=LlamaForCausalLM(
  (mode...es=128256, bias=False)
), input_type=LlamaForCausalLM]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.9/v/is_instance_of
llm.is-instance[Runnable]
  Input should be an instance of Runnable [type=is_instance_of, input_value=LlamaForCausalLM(
  (mode...es=128256, bias=False)
), input_type=LlamaForCausalLM]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.9/v/is_instance_of


What is the error  indicating and how to resolve it?
Google gave me few links but the relevant ones mentioned to upgrade either langchain or pydantic.
